# How can I convert excel file to pdf using .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I'm new working with .Net Standard 2.0. I want to convert excel files to pdf using a free API. I have tried to install via NuGet many APIs like `SautinSoft.ExcelToPdf`, `Winnovative.ExcelToPdf` and `EvoPdf.ExcelToPdf` without success. I don't want to use interop because according to reviews is a bad choise.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17574/Programmatically-Convert-Documents-to-PDFs-the-Eas) or [this](http://neevia.com/support/examples/dpsdk/?get=ex004cnet) or [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). Refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp) also

Comment: What do you mean *without succes*? Where is your code even if it is without success so someone may help you.

Comment: Also, what is the goal? a .net standard library is supposed to run on many frameworks and platforms, if you want a .net standard library that works on e.g. mono on iOS, those libraries aren't going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because you are install the .NET framework libraries to the .NET Standard project. **This packages may not fully compatible with your project**. You can get this warning after install those packages:

[image]

So just as Martin`s comment, if you want to convert excel files to pdf with .Net Standard 2.0, those only have .NET framework libraries packages would not help you.